При парсинге не находит строку в спане
Учусь париснгу, пытаюсь найти товары со скидкой и вывести ссылку на товар + скидку. Мой код:
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import *
from requests import get
import time


def main():
    # список скидок в том формате в котором они содержатся в спанах
    discounts = [(f'-{i}%') for i in range(20, 100)]
    print()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Убедитесь, что у вас установлен ChromeDriver

    # Открываем страницу
    url = 'https://www.ozon.ru/category/perchatki-i-varezhki-muzhskie-17104/?category_was_predicted=true&deny_category_prediction=true&from_global=true&is_high_rating=t&text=перчатки+зимние+мужские'
    driver.get(url)

    # Даем время на загрузку страницы
    time.sleep(20)  # Пауза для полной загрузки контента

    # Получаем HTML-код страницы
    html_code = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'html.parser')

    # Теперь можно искать нужный div
    main_div = soup.find('div', class_='j7z_23')
    # Проверяем, найден ли div
    if main_div:
        print('Found main div')
        # Ищем все div с нужными атрибутами внутри найденного div
        tile_divs = main_div.find_all('div', {'data-index': True, 'class': 'rj8_23 rj9_23 tile-root'})
        if tile_divs:
            print('found divs...')
        # Проходим по каждому найденному div
        for tile_div in tile_divs:
            # Находим span с нужным классом
            span = tile_div.find('span', class_='tsBodyControl400Small c3019-a6 c3019-b4')
            #print(span)
            for s in discounts:
                # print(span.index(s))
                if s in span:

                # Находим ссылку внутри текущего div
                    link = tile_div.find('a', class_='jt1_23 tile-hover-target t1j_23')
                    if link:
                     # Выводим ссылку и текст в кавычках
                        print(link['href'], s)
    else:
        print("Div не найден.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Он ничего не находит и не выводит, хотя всё должно работать. Я пробовал отлаживать, выводить спаны и т. д., всё так как надо, но при этом он не считает что s входит хоть в какой-то span. Подскажите в чём ошибка
